# How do I add a checkbox to PdfCell in iTestSharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, pdf, itext

I am generating a PDF and would like to add locked check boxes (both checked and unchecked, depending on the data received) with the label. I am not sure how to do that.

```
cell.Phrase = new Phrase("Photos", boldFont);
table.AddCell(cell);
```

The checkbox should go before the "Photos" label. I have done some research and I cannot find anything that has what I am looking for. Can someone help?!

Thanks in advance!